# Try to understand the SQL query in Kotlin, to get null returned when database query return Empty set

Tags: mysql, kotlin, mybatis

I'm reading an existing private project code, but I don't understand some Kotlin code about the SQL query.

Here is the DAO statement:

```
interface UserMapper {

    @Select("SELECT userId, phoneNumber FROM users WHERE phoneNumber=#{number} LIMIT 1")
    fun getUserByPhoneNumber(number: String?): User
}
```

And `User` is defined like this:

```
public class User {

        private int userId;
        private String phoneNumber;
}
```

Then I call it as follows:

```
val user = userMapper!!.getUserByPhoneNumber(phonenumber)
if (user != null) {
    doSomething()
} else {
    doOtherthing()
}
```

The first question is about the function `getUserByPhoneNumber`, does it simply return the User object?

The second is about the build warning:

```
[WARNING] Condition 'user != null' is always 'true'
```

How can I fix this to handle the case when query an user which doesn't exist in database?

[Updated]:

This is an usage of `UserMapping` with `mybatis-spring`, the reference document is [here](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html) and [here](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html#)

Comment: 1. We have no idea of which framework/API you use to execute those queries. 2. The number argument should be of type String, not String?, since passing null doesn't make sense. 3. If the framework/API returns null when the resultset is empty, then the return type should be User?, not User. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: It's springframework. number is String.

Comment: It's not Spring Framework. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/: it doesn't have any Select class. And no, number is not of type String. It's of type String?. Read your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first question is about the function getUserByPhoneNumber, does it simply return the User object?**

Yes `getUserByPhoneNumber` returns simply an object. Actually it depends on your `Select query`.

**The second is about the build warning**

You are returning `User` from `getUserByPhoneNumber` that is not nullable and you are checking for `null`, this is the reason of this warning.

To remove warning just add `?` to the return type `User` like following:

```
interface UserMapper {

    @Select("SELECT userId, phoneNumber FROM users WHERE phoneNumber=#{number} LIMIT 1")
    fun getUserByPhoneNumber(number: String?): User?

}
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have further question.

Comment: Thanks, the `User?` do remove the build warning. I will check if the returned   User object is null when query return Empty set.

Comment: Still confused about the `getUserByPhoneNumber` function return object, how it knows it's a `User` object? If my `class User` definition is different from the `select query`, what will happen? for example, if I change the select as `@Select("SELECT userId FROM users WHERE phoneNumber=#{number} LIMIT 1")`

Comment: @gary to know that you need to know which SQL to object mapper you're using, and then read its documentation. My guess is that it's MyBatis: http://www.mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html. Don't you have team-mates who can give you an introduction on this project?

Comment: Yes, I find `mybatis` `3.3.0` in the pom.xml, thanks for your hint, a very long list of dependency and hard to find it.  And unfortunately the writer already left the company so no teammate know this code.

Comment: @gary Whatever you select values in your SELECT query, variable with same name should be in your class(or use `@ColumnInfo` annotation). If Room compiler finds any inconsistencies, there will be compile time error i guess. Check official documentation on google developer website its really simple with several examples.